# Passing validation errors array from one controller to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have **Comment** belongs_to **Post** and **Post** has_many **Comments**, the comment model as following:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

The form which adds new comments is located in **Posts** show view, as following:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @post, @post.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
    <% if @comment.errors.any?%>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <ul>
            <% @comment.errors.messages.values.each do |msg| %>
              <%msg.each do  |m| %>
                 <li><%= m %></li>
              <%end %>
             <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <p>
       <%= form.text_area :text , {placeholder: true}%>
    </p>

    <p>
       <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

The **Comments** create action, as following:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.post_id = params[:post_id]
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
        render 'posts/show'
    end
end



private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
    end
end
```

I need to render the posts/show page to show **Comment** validation errors, but the problem is I'm in **CommentsController** controller not PostsController so all objects used in pages/show view will be null.

How can I pass the @comment object to pages/show?
I thought about using **flash** array, but I'm looking for more conventional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, rendering `pages/show` will just use the view template, but not the action, so anything you define in the `pages#show` controller action won't be available. `@comment` will be available though as you define that in the `comments#create` action. Without seeing the `PostsController` I don't know what else you're loading in the `pages#show` action - you could consider moving anything required in both to a method on `ApplicationController`, then calling from both places. Another option would be to change your commenting process to work via AJAX (`remote: true` instead of `local: true` on the form), and responding with JS designed to re-render just the comment form (you can move it into a partial used both in `pages/show.html.erb` and the `comments#create` response).

Couple of other notes on your code above - in `comments#create`, you can use:

```
@comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
```

to avoid needing to set the `post_id` on `@comment` manually.

For the form, I'd be tempted to setup a new comment in `pages#show`:

```
@comment = @post.comments.build
```

And then reference that in the form, it'll make it easier if you do re-use that between `pages#show` and `comments#create`:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @post, @comment ], local: true) do |form| %>
```

Hope that helps!